# FBConnect Deprecated Endpoint Error

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, fbconnect

I am doing facebook integration part in my project. I downloaded facebook integration sample project from rey wenderlich and then changed appkey and appsecretkey. When I run this app, login validation is working fine and then it shows error.this comes in the same popup after login .

**Error: This endpoint has been deprecated. To temporarily reenable it,you may disable the “august_2012” platform migration.I will be permanently disabled on August 1 ,2012**

How to fix this error
The functionality I am using is the same of the FbConnect sample code

```
- (void)session:(FBSession*)session didLogin:(FBUID)uid {

self.usersession =session;
NSLog(@"User with id %lld logged in.", uid);
[self getFacebookName];
}

- (void)getFacebookName {
NSString* fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:
             @"select uid,name from user where uid == %lld", self.usersession.uid];
NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fql forKey:@"query"];
[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.fql.query" params:params];
self.post=YES;
}
```

Comment: use the lalest verison of FBConnect . may be it resolved :)

Comment: Can you provide me the link. previous I downloaded from the third party site..can you give me the link..I am not getting

Comment: try looking on developers.facebook.com there are links to the latest code samples on there.

Answer (score 0):

[This has a nice documentation with examples](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/)